# Radare2: Running executable from a specific point

Tags: debugging, binary-analysis, radare2, crackme

I am using radare2 to reverse engineer a standard crackme executable. I have obtained the password, but now I need use the program to read & print a restricted file to which the executable has access.

I can see from the executable's main function through radare2 that there is a "login" section that asks for a password and this then proceeds to execute a system command that prints the restricted file.

However, it seems the program flow skips past this section and terminates the program.

Given an address or a string reference, how can I use radare2 to execute the program from a certain point so that I can avoid skipping it?

From this:

```
entry point 0x00000
|
|  desired section 0x000c8 "enter password: "
v
termination 0x000f9 "no entry"
```

To this:

```
entry point
|
|_-> desired section 0x000c8 "enter password: " -> 0x000ca "cat /root/file.txt" -
                                                                                 |
termination 0x000f9 <-___________________________________________________________|
```

Comment: why not just set `rip` to the desired address?

Comment: How does `rip` differ from seek?

Comment: seek is only where you are in the code. rip points to what's being executed

Comment: I tried setting `rip` to the desired address and continued execution with `dc` and it ended up terminating prematurely with a memory error.

Comment: well, it might be not as easy as like this, there might be some initialization being done that you've skipped.Show the real code, add link to the "program" so ppl can have a look at this specific example.